# Version control elements in a database-table using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am developing a database using MySQL. Database (shopping) consists of one table (basket). When the customer comes in and purchase groceries those to be stored in the table by unique customer Id. For example, a customer named ABC came to my store, purchased 10 apples, and made bill. After 4 hours, he returned four apples to the shop, took money of them, and left. Therefore, I need to version control those records in my table, to see the track of the customer.

MySQL code:

```
SHOW DATABASES; 

CREATE DATABASE shopping;  

USE shopping;   

CREATE TABLE basket (Customer_ID VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, Phone INT, grocery VARCHAR (10), QTY INT, Timestamp, Version VARCHAR (10));
```

## The table looks like

```
Customer_ID Phone   Grocery QTY Timestamp   Version
ABC 34567   Apple   10  1/20/2020 7:00 am   A1
ABC 34567   banana  5   1/20/2020 7:00 am   B1
ABC 34567   oranges 4   1/20/2020 7:00 am   O1
DEF 12345   jelly   10  1/20/2020 8:00am    J1
DEF 12345   pineapple   6   1/20/2020 8:00am    P1
GHI 67854   juice   4   1/20/2020 9:00 am   J1
GHI 67854   icecream    6   1/20/2020 9:00 am   I1
ABC 34567   Apple   -4  1/20/2020 11:00 am  A2
```

No I need to get the second instance of customer ABC when he return four apples to the shop and version it as A2, so i could track all the changes on each customer.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but I think you are mixing up different domain concepts here.  A customer is an entity on its own - with a customer ID and phone number.  What you refer to as the basket, I would rather call a stock transaction - an item, quantity, timestamp, and a link to a customer.  That also doesn't feel like something that should have a version - items go out or they come back in.  The timestamp and customer ID should be enough to infer a 'version' of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks @Riaan Nel, If the customer goes in and comes back and exchange the same item it should versioned (eg: for first instance A1 is version and if he return the same product A2 will be second version), please ignore phone number.